# Why does mutate not act like I expect in this code?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a confusion regarding how the mutate in tidyverse/ dplyr works. I have included a reproducible example here. One uses mutate and one uses a loop. I would expect both to give the same result, but they do not. I have no idea why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(x = c('a,a,b,b,b','a,a','a,b,b,b,c,c,c'))
# Approach 1 (mutate)
d %>% 
  mutate(y = paste(unique(str_split(x, ',')[[1]]), collapse = ','))
d
# Approach 2 (loop)
for (i in 1:nrow(d))
{
  d$y[i] <- paste(unique(str_split(d$x[i], ',')[[1]]), collapse = ',')
}
d
```

I expect output to be the same for both approaches, but they are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is that we are subsetting only first `list` element with `[[1]]` and then the `unique` is only on that element.  Instead, we need to loop through the `list` (from `str_split` output)

```
library(tidyverse) 
d %>%
     mutate(y = str_split(x, ',') %>%  # output is a list
                   map_chr(~ unique(.x) %>% # loop with map, get the unique elements 
                    toString)) # paste the strings together
#             x       y
#1     a,a,b,b,b    a, b
#2           a,a       a
#3 a,b,b,b,c,c,c a, b, c
```

---

In the `for` loop, it was not the case because the splitting was done one element at a time `str_split(d$x[i]`

---

To understand better, the `str_split` (`strsplit` base R`) is vectorized.  They can take multiple strings and split into a`list`of`vector`s equal to the length of the intial vector

```
str_split(d$x, ',') # list of length 3
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a" "a"

#[[3]]
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
```

Extracting the first `[[1]]`

```
str_split(d$x, ',')[[1]]
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
```

In the `for` loop, we are individually splitting the elements and extract the list (length 1) element

```
str_split(d$x[1], ',')[[1]]
#[1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "b"
str_split(d$x[2], ',')[[1]]
#[1] "a" "a"
```

That is the reason, we need to loop over the `list` and then get the `unique` from each of the elements

Comment: Does that mean that "mutate" does not perform calculation one element at a time? So, the "x" in mutate is the entire column and not one cell at a time?

Comment: @PraGalaxy  It has nothing to do with `mutate`.  You can check `str_split(d$x, ",")` returns a `list` of `vectors`.  When you do `[[1]]`, you are extracting only the first element of the `list`

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it now. Also, I did some research and figured out that "mutate" is applied to the column at once. It works fine with functions that are vectorized. But here, str_split is not vectorized and outputs a list, hence the issue. Is this correct?

Comment: @PraGalaxy  The `str_split` is vectorized and that is the reason it is splititng more than 1 element at a time into a `list` of `vector`s.  In the `for` loop` you are splitting one element/string (`d$x[i]`) at a time and that is the difference.  But, in one both cases, `strsplit` returns a list.  Tje difference is the length of the `list`.  Here, it would be a `list` of length 3.  So, if there is a `list` of length 1, then extract it with `[[1]]`, it returns the element.  For list of length 3, doing the same returns only first